# Validate associated object (lazy validation)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I'm trying to solve validation of associated object with condition.

User doesn't need to have filled `author_bio` until he is author. So app needs to ensure, that author can't create post without `author_bio` and `author_bio` can't be deleted if user already created any post.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, foreign_key: 'author_id', inverse_of: :author

  validates :author_bio, presence: { if: :author? }

  def author?
    posts.any?
  end 
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :posts, required: true
end
```

Unfortunately this doesn't validate author on creation of new post:

```
user = User.first
user.author_bio
=> nil

post = Post.new(author: user)
post.valid?
=> true
post.save
=> true
post.save
=> false
post.valid?
=> false
```

So how can I prevent creating of new post by user without `author_bio`? I can add second validation to `Post` model, but this is not DRY. Is there any better solution?

Answer (score 0):

The answer here seems to be use of `validates_associated` once you have your associations correctly set up (including `inverse_of` which you have, but stating for others, rails in many cases misses them or creates them incorrectly)

so to adjust the classes here:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, foreign_key: 'author_id', inverse_of: :author

  validates :author_bio, presence: { if: :author? }

  def author?
    posts.any?
  end 
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :posts

  validates :author, presence: true                                                   
  validates_associated :author
end
```

Now when you try running what you did before:

```
user = User.first
user.author_bio
=> nil

post = Post.new(author: user)
post.valid?
=> false
post.save
=> false
```

Does not allow you to save since `author_bio` is empty

Only thing to watch out there was to set up correct associations, otherwise rails was confused and skipping validation on `User` class since it thought the relationship is not yet in existence.

NOTE: I removed `required: true` from `belongs_to` since in rails 5 is default, therefore you won't need `validates :author, presence: true` either only in rails 5.